# Magento 2 admin panel login not working. I am getting an error

Tags: magento2

> [2020-01-20 07:41:49] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats!
>   Warning!stat(): stat failed for
>   D:/local.webstore/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot
>   gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for
>   D:/local.webstore/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
>   at
>   D:\local.webstore\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php:73)"}
>   []

Comment: anyone help me very urgent please??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please perform below command. There is permission issue of files and directory, Please run below command in Magento root directory.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a permission issue of files and directory.
Please check the following link

> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Main-CRITICAL-Cannot-gather-stats/m-p/112240/highlight/true#M7208

Maybe it'll help you.